# CodeIgniter Route Matching Two Numbers With Optional Decimals

Tags: php, regex, codeigniter

trying to match something like:

`wrs/time/5/10` or `wrs/time/5.2/10.55` or anything in between an integer and float up to two optional decimal places for both capture groups.

have been trying the following which works for one number but not for both groups: `\d{0,2}(\.\d{1,2})?`

full route attempt:

```
$route['wrs/time/(\d{0,2}(\.\d{1,2})?)/(\d{0,2}(\.\d{1,2})?)'] = 'wrs/trange/$1/$2';
```

any help much appreciated

Comment: can you please edit the question with What is it that you are getting? and what are you expecting?

Comment: Your code works fine when I tested it in one of my projects.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your current regex works but puts the full numbers into groups 1 and 3 (with the decimals also on their own in groups 2 and 4).

You can fix this by changing your rewrite to `'wrs/trange/$1/$3'`.

Alternatively you can change your regex very slightly to:

```
wrs/time/(\d{0,2}(?:\.\d{1,2})?)/(\d{0,2}(?:\.\d{1,2})?)
```

By changing the `(...)` around the decimal part to `(?:...)` you say don't capture the decimal in its own group, so your numbers will be in group 1 and 2 like you expect.

This is often useful when as in your example you need to group something in brackets so that you can use a `?` to make the whole thing optional, but you don't actually want that part to be a capture group.

[RegExr](http://regexr.com?37e2a)

Comment: `{0,2}+` doesn't mean "between zero and 2 times, one or more times" but "between zero and 2 times, possessive".

Comment: Yeah I realised as I typed it that I had no idea `{0,2}+` would actually do - I was pretty certain it was invalid regex. I had no idea something could be "possessive" (nor did the person who wrote the regex), just looked it up now, thanks for the info.